# How to map a datasource for a java web service

Tags: java, jboss, datasource, jndi

I'm trying to figure out how to use datasources for my web service.  I have the oracle-ds.xml deployed on my jboss 4.2.3 server, and the datasources are showing as bounded to JNDI names java:TestDS, java:WeatherDS, etc.

I try doing an initialcontext.lookup but I can't find it.  I tried referencing the resource in the web.xml but I get "java:WeatherDS has no valid JNDI binding"... I've tried referencing "java:/WeatherDS", "WeatherDS", "java:WeatherDS", "jdbc/WeatherDS" and some others, but I think I need to somehow map the reference name to the jndi name.

I found a snippet of code that says:

```
...
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DefaultDS</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:/DefaultDS</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
...
```

But, it doesn't say where this file is and what else is needed.  I don't know if I need a resource reference for sure or not.  Can anyone point me in the direction of some more complete information of how to access the datasource from the code once it has been deployed?  I am trying to make it so the connections are pooled for my web service.

Comment: JNDI lookup is the way. Can you confirm in your startup logs that the datasource actually deploys?

Comment: I get the following when starting the server, I just haven't been able to reference it=====> 11:33:55,364 INFO [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=WeatherDS' to JNDI name 'java:WeatherDS' I tried adding the <jndi-name> into a jboss-web.xml file but I still cannot lookup the datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JBoss-4.2.3 you define a datasource in an XML-File in folder **[JBOSS_HOME]/server/[MYSERVER]/deploy/**

Create a file in this folder with name: **mydatasource-ds.xml**.

XML-File content:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>mydatasource</jndi-name>
    <!-- Properties for SQLServer -->
    <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hostname:1433/db-name;TDS=8.0;lastUpdateCount=true;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false</connection-url>
    <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <!-- Properties for SQLServer end -->
    <user-name>name</user-name>
    <password>pwd</password>
    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>15000</blocking-timeout-millis>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

To can access these datasource from every application deployed in the same JBoss by normal JNDI lookup.

IMPORTANT: Use prefix **java:/** in the jndi name in your code. Full JNDI-Name in your application for the datasource above is **java:/mydatasource**